# Nicely throwing an error in gulp task

Tags: javascript, error-handling, gulp

I am creating a gulp task which might fail under certain circumstances.

```
gulp.task('favicon', function () {
  try {
    require('child_process').execSync('icotool --version');
  } catch( e ) {
    var err = new Error( 'Unix bash and icotool required for generating favicon' );
    throw err;
  }

  return gulp.src('', {read: false})
    .pipe(shell([
      './generate-favicon.sh'
    ]));
});
```

When running my task via gulp and running into the error, the error will be presented rather ugly.
I would like to present the error in a way as it is done by e.g. jslint gulp-util's `PluginError`.

It actually works to just create a `PluginError` there and throw it but that doesn't seem quite right.
Another solution not that nice would be to set

```
err.showStack = false;
```

for at least a little nicer error output. A `gulp.task.Error` would be nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I've seen its not great to throw an error from gulp.  But I found this blog entry that I used to work for me.

http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/how-to-generate-error-in-gulp-task/

**Edit**: [`gulp-util` has been deprecated](https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5). Instead, use [the `plugin-error` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plugin-error).

My Example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var error = require('plugin-error');
gulp.task('deploy', function(cb) {
  if(typeof(specialId) === 'undefined') {
    var err = new PluginError({
      plugin: 'deploy',
      message: 'specialId is empty.'
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, seems like I was looking for. That blog post just came up a few days after my original question :)