# Gulp- Make sure file has comments in the beginning

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have multiple javascript files in a folder and I want to make sure that every file has comment in the beginning (that will explain the summary of file).

```
/*
 This file will......
*/
function test () {
....
}
```

So is this possible using gulp-contains or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the regex provided by @Sajjad in previous answer. I have managed to achieve my goal. I have used gulp-if and gulp-fail instead (I find it more flexible).

Here is how I do that:

```
var condition = function (file) {
    sFile = require('path').parse(file.path).name;
    var startWithComment = file.contents.toString().replace(/\n|\r/g, "").trim().startsWith("/*");
    return (!startWithComment);
}


gulp.task('taskName',
    function() {
        gulp.src('files/*.js')
            .pipe(gulpIf(condition, fail(function () {
                var message = 'Some message';
                return message;
            })));
    });
```

Comment: Great! \o/ Sorry for incompleteness!

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be enough just to make sure if start of a file is the comment initial characters (`/*`)

```
    gulp.src('./file.js')
    .pipe(map(function(file, callback) {
        var startWithComment = file.contents.toString().replace(/\n|\r/g, "").trim().startsWith("/*");
        if (startWithComment){
             // DO YOUR CHORES
        }
    }))
```

Another approach is to split the initial text to make sure if it is a valid multi-line comment.

```
function startsWithValidMultiLineComment(str){
     try{
          return str.replace(/\n|\r/g, "").trim().split("/*")[1].split("*/")[1].length > 0         
     } catch (e){
         return false;
     }
}
```

Following this approach `str.split("/*")[1].split("*/")[0]` would be your comment text

Comment: Thanks alot, but what if there is an empty line in the beginning or empty spaces in the beginning?

Comment: `str.replace(/\n|\r|\s/g, "")`  is doing that for you @Ask

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try

Comment: `str.replace(/\n|\r/g, "").trim()` is more precise @Ask

Comment: can you tell me 1 more thing. I am totally new to gulp. I want to throw error if it's not found i.e if(!startswithcomment){throw error.} I was trying to use PluginError but it's not working, Can you tell me how can I throw error

Comment: Means I want to fail gulp task if the file not starts with comment

Comment: @ask How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734769/nicely-throwing-an-error-in-gulp-task) ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, With the help of your regex.  I have found another way to achieve this. Please look at my answer.